# PHP Delete MySQL Records Older Than 3 Days

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following at the top of every page so when the website is loaded by anyone PHP deletes any record in a specific database table that is older than 3 days.

```
$conn = getConnected("oversizeBoard");
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM postedLoads WHERE date < DATE_SUB(DATE('m-d-Y'), INTERVAL 3 DAY");
```

The problem is nothing is being deleted.

The data type for my date column is `varchar(20)` and when I insert a date into MySQL it is entered using `date("m-d-Y")`. The name of my date field is `date`. So it appears that the above query would be correct, but I have done something wrong, and I am not certain as to what since every example I've looked at has basically looked the same except they used `now()` instead of `date()` but I use a specific date format so I can't use `now()` in my query.

What have I done wrong?

I even tried putting it into a function:

```
function deleteOversizeRows() {
$conn = getConnected("oversizeBoard");
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM postedLoads WHERE date < DATE_SUB(DATE('m-d-Y'), INTERVAL 3 DAY");
}
deleteOversizeRows();
```

Comment: Why your column is `varchar`? Shouldn't it be `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: Because the user selects a date from a dropdown that generates days from today to two weeks from today. So all of the `options` look like `<option value="01-05-2012">`

Comment: And as far as I knew `date` or `datetime` required a specific format, but I pull the date from the table and show it back to users in that format.

Comment: I suppose the problem is in column type. Have you tried your query directly on your db? Via phpmyadmin or console? Try to create tmp table with proper field type (date/datetime) and execute your query. If it's the cause of problem - you'll have to alter your table.

Comment: `WHERE  str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)` That double quote inside the query at the end doesnt belong there also

Comment: That actually deleted them all lol even the ones posted today. It's all test stuff so it doesn't matter if it disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to provide date by calculating first and then use it in query like below

```
$date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime('-3 day'));
$conn = getConnected("oversizeBoard");
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM postedLoads WHERE date < '".$date."');
```

It might help you. If need any other solution or help, do ask here.

Comment: You were missing a `)` at the end of the last line, but after fixing that and removing the `"` I got it to work with 
`$date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime('-3 day'));
$conn = getConnected("oversizeBoard");
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM postedLoads WHERE date < '$date' ");` Thanks :)

Comment: Ahh... Thanks for notice this. Some time small mistakes happen but guys like you making correct them. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL function `TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2);`

Function calculates difference between two dates and returns output based on the unit parameter passed .

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM postedLoads WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF('DAY',date,now())<3;
```

For detailed info of function:http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php